# Install Powerpoint 2007 Add-In in Powerpoint 2010

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

When using Powerpoint 2010: is it possible to install a Powerpoint 2007 Add-In?

I have a Add-In which is a dll file packaged with other files. It was designed for Office 2007. When trying to install the Add-In, the following message shows up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how the add-in is written.  Generally, installing an add-in that targets an older version into a newer version should cause no problems, but obviously that's not the case with this particular add-in.  You'd need to contact the developer to learn why, though.